# Want to retrieve book info using open API

Tags: php, jquery, html

It's not very long since I have studied php and html.
Recently I'm trying to retrieve book info using open API, but it's hard for me to figure out 'cause I'm not used to json and etc.
Here is my source. I'm confused why this is not working. I want to get some help. Thank you in advance.

```
 <?php
 $ISBN = _POST['barcode'];
 $post_data = array(
 "page" => 1,
 "search_field1" => "ISBN",
 "value1" => "$ISBN",
 "maxCount" => 1,
 "per_page" => 1,
 "collection_set" => 1
 );
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://nl.go.kr/kolisnet/openApi/open.php");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
 curl_exec($ch);

 print_r($ch);
 ?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>barcode</title>
 </head>
 <body>

 <form action="barcode.php" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="barcode" ">
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
 </form>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] and make an effort - explain your __not working__

Comment: What, specifically, isn't working? Are you not getting the output you expected from the cURL-call? Or are you getting warnings and errors about using `_POST` instead of `$_POST`?

Comment: I want to get output but, whenever I put different ISBN numbers, it show only same result on my localhost. When I test this on aws server, any result is not seen.